# Copy All Type of Files in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a simple program to copy file of any type. I write the code as below.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

public class CopyExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File f = new File("image.jpg");
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("copy-image.png");
    byte[] ar = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    is.read(ar);
    os.write(ar);
    is.close();
    os.close();
  }
}
```

I already tested this code for `.txt` , `.jpg` , `.png`, `.pdf` It is working fine.

But I want to ask is it fine? or is there any other way to do this in better way?

Comment: if file is bigger then it's worst case. read file partly basis.

Comment: @vishalgajera example please? and how?

Comment: see this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177994/java-read-file-and-split-into-multiple-files

Answer (score 1):

Copying a file is not about its file extension or type. It is about its content. If file is so big maybe computer's memory will not be enough.

[Apache's FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) may be useful for your question.

[this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9235401/517134) may help you.

And [this article](http://www.journaldev.com/861/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java) is about your question

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 provides `Files` class  that you could use to copy a file

```
Files.copy(src,dest);
```